# How to get the screen resolution including the size of soft keyboard?

Tags: android

My phone is HUAWEI NXT-AL10, and I can see its resolution is **1080 x 1920** from the system settings page, But when I try to writing some codes as below to retrieving its screen resolution, the value is **1080 x 1794**, I guess maybe it doesn't include the size of soft-keyboard. So How can I get the resolution just like as the settings page said (1080 x 1920)?

```
    DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
    int width = metric.widthPixels;
    int height = metric.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should give you what you're looking for

```
Point size = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
iWidth = size.x;
iHeight = size.y;

Log.i(TAG, "Screen real size (pixels) :width = " + iWidth);
Log.i(TAG, "Screen real size (pixels) :height = " + iHeight);
```

Note that this requires API 17 and above

Comment: I tried, it works very well on API 17, and is there have way to get the real size on API 16?

Comment: I've been away over the weekend and just seen your comment. I had just copied some code I was using for providing metrics for one of my apps. I like your full response below. However are `getHeight` and `getWidth` deprecated in API13?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @SimonH answer, and I add more logic to support API 16 and below, here they are just for your reference:

```
private void initScreenSize() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        Point size = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
        mScreenWidth = size.x;
        mScreenHeight = size.y;
    } else {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        try {
            Method getHeight = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
            Method getWidth = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
            mScreenWidth = (Integer) getHeight.invoke(display);
            mScreenHeight = (Integer) getWidth.invoke(display);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mScreenWidth = display.getWidth();
            mScreenHeight = display.getHeight();
        }
    }
}
```